# Configure Application Insights agent for Java Function Apps

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-java-tools

I enabled the Application Insights agent for my Java Function App as described at [How to enable distributed tracing for Java Function apps?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-functions#how-to-enable-distributed-tracing-for-java-function-apps)

```
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Java="1"
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION="~2"
```

While it collects a lot of useful telemetry data, it creates `traces` of the `ExecutionContext#getLogger()` twice. The duplicated entries contain different `customDimensions` (e.g. `{"LoggingLevel":"INFO","SourceType":"Logger"}`) and are create just before the regular entries.

In addition, the `sdkVersion` property of the trace entry contains `awr_java:3.0.2` instead of `azurefunctions: 3.0.15733.0`.

I would like to disable the Auto collected `Logger` messages, but I have 2 issues.

1. How can I provide the agent configuration `applicationinsights.json` within the Azure Functions environment?
2. Which property needs to be set to disable the additional `Logger` entries?

[Configuration options - Azure Monitor Application Insights for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config) suggests to put the `applicationinsights.json` next to the agent or set path via `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONFIGURATION_FILE`. Since the agent and also the destination of the deployed Function App is managed by the runtime, it isn't obvious, how to setup the agent appropriately.

Comment: This [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview#supported-environments-languages-and-resource-providers) indicate that azure function seems not support app insights agent yet.

Comment: And I think you can enable function's application insights when you creating the instance, but not through agent. See this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration

Comment: @TinyWang, thanks for your comments. The agent is already in place and collects telementry data, but the feature is currently in preview. My question is about the configuration of the agent.

Comment: Seems a known bug, [Distributed Tracing enabled - logs are duplicated](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/385). :/

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, and I always enable app insights in the function by 'click the enable button'. And your finding is very helpful, sorry for not offering help...